# Google analytics reports that a deleted blog still receives traffic

Tags: seo, google-analytics, blog

I had a blog on my WordPress site and I deleted it a couple of months ago but I still notice sessions to this page in my Google Analytics Results.

What are the possible measures I can take to stop showing up for old keyword?

edit: I receive traffic from following channels to these pages: (Other), Display, Direct, Organic Search, Referral, and Email.

Comment: If it is deleted, how is Google Analytics tracking it?   The tracking snippet shouldn't be on "404 Not Found" pages.